# -ms-appearance, -0-appearance, and appearance showing up as error in editor.

Tags: css

I have the following code in my css:

```
header input{
width:100%;
height:50px;
float:left;
color:fff;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius:25px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
border: 0px;
box-shadow: none;
outline: none;

-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-ms-appearance:none;
-o-appearance: none;
appearance: none;

}
```

I'm using Webstorm as my editor, and this code is showing up as an error:

```
-ms-appearance:none;
-o-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

Am i doing something wrong, or is the editor just acting up?

Comment: This is a nonstandard CSS property, so I wouldn't put too much stock in it if your target browser is rendering it appropriately, especially since you are using the value `none`. But the reason for the error might be that the erroring lines are not in-use prefixes. AFAIK only webkit and moz are used.

Comment: See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The five main browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari & Opera) use a mix of `-moz-appearance` and `-webkit-appearance`. It is not supported in IE. So what your editor is telling you here is not that they are necessarily wrong, just there is no point having them.

For some reason Edge uses `-webkit-appearance` instead of `-ms-appearance`

I would change your code to:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
```

so that it is correct for all major browsers and is future proof, as sometime soon `appearance` will loose its prefixes.